# Explicit variable template specialization with different types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T v;

template <>
double v<char> = 123.456; // ???

int main() {
    std::cout << v<int> << " " << v<char> << "\n";
}
```

Why I'm allowed ([gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h4sSOEcaEVubxZqm), [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cYMEUbuuCBzhWAWZ)) to specialize template variable for `char` type as `double`? What's the correct syntax for variable template specialization?

Comment: *"What's the correct syntax for variable template specialization?"* Your syntax is correct.